# Return variable from object

Tags: ajax, variables, object, return

I need to return result variable from this code, I am trying it about hour, but still with no successs... Can You help me please? I studied object too, but without success...

```
api.prototype.ajax = function()
{
    marmottajax({
                            url: "http://localhost:8080/bp/stranka/api/test",
                            method: "post",
                            parameters: 
                            {
                                image: 8,
                                by: "click"
                            }
                        }).then(function(result) 
                        {
                            result; //this variable i want to get/return to my function
                        });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't `return` from an AJAX call - you either need to use promises or a callback. Here's an example with a callback:

```
api.prototype.ajax = function(callback) {
    marmottajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/bp/stranka/api/test",
        method: "post",
        parameters: {
            image: 8,
            by: "click"
        }
    }).then(function(result) {
        callback(result); //this variable i want to get/return to my function
    });
}
```

And use it:

```
api.ajax(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: It does not solve my problem, because I need this variable as output of my function, client that use my API do not want to use this... There is maybe synchronous ajax, but I did not try it how it works with canvas game, maybe game will be freezing :/

Comment: @Raiper34 -- Synchronous ajax will cause the UI to completely lock - if that's acceptable then use that. Else, you won't be able to assign the result of this function to a variable.

Answer (score 1):

I have just learn about promise :P, may be I could help. Because I see you are using then, I wonder if you are using Promise.If you are using Promise, in the function, there should be two params `resolved`, `rejected`, You can pass your return value via `resolved` function.

Here is an example that could help you! [source url](http://www.javascripture.com/Promise)

```
var promise = new Promise(
function(resolve, reject) {
  console.log('in Promise constructor function');
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('in setTimeout callback');
    if (Math.random() > 0.5){
      resolve('Here is your data');
    } else {
      reject('Something happend, it causes error');
    } 
  }, 100);
});
console.log('created promise');
promise.then(
  function(result) {
    console.log('promise returned: ' + result);
  },
  function(err){
    console.log(err);
  }
);
console.log('hooked promise.then()');
```

Comment: It does not solve my problem, because I need this variable as output of my function, client that use my API do not want to use this... There is maybe synchronous ajax, but I did not try it how it works with canvas game, maybe game will be freezing :/